# How to loop in <div> HERE <div/>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, powershell

I have created a loop outside the code and i decided later to put inside of a HTML/jquery Table but everytime I copy paste it doesnt work at all. Is there any posibility to put the foreach inside the ? [Here is the Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLnh8.png) "in the "LOOP" should be the generated text through foreach"

```
$rows += @"
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Deutsch (DE)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Englisch (EN)</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>LOOP 1</p>
     </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>LOOP 2</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    "@
```

the loop

```
$tfsWis.Query("Select * from sth where [sample]  <> '' order by [Iteration Path] desc, Id desc") | Foreach-Object `
{
    $backgroundColor = 'background-color:green; color:white;'
    $item = $_
    if($oldIteration -and $oldIteration -ne $item.IterationPath)
    {
        $rows += @"
                </ul> 
        </ul> 
"@ 
    }
    if($oldIteration -ne $item.IterationPath)
    {
        $rows += @"
        <ul>        
            <li><div>$($item.Fields["it"].value) </div> </li>
                    <ul>

"@ 
    }
    $rows += @"
                    <li><div>$($item.Fields["ID"].value)</div></li>
                        <ul> 
                            <li>
                                <div>Title<br/>$($item.Fields["en"].value)</div>
                            </li>
                            <li> 
                                <div>Description<br/>$($item.Fields["deen"].value)</div>  
                            </li> 

                            <li>
                                <div>Titel<br/>$($item.Fields["dee"].value)</div>
                            </li> 
                            <li> 
                                <div>Beschreibung<br/>$($item.Fields["es"].value)</div> 
                            </li> 
                        </ul> 
"@
    $oldIteration = $item.IterationPath
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question exactly?

Comment: It doesn't make it any clearer, do you just want to generate multiple tabs? Can you re-read your question without knowing what you mean and see if you understand what should come out of this question as an answer? Also explain from where the @ is coming, it seems to come from a server side program (potentially C#) though these tags are not inside your question

Comment: they come from powershell... so i generated a loop for example "1..100" i want to put these numbers into the table. i hope it is now clearer :)

Comment: Can you add the loop that you have created? Or at least from where the data is coming from so that one can give you a more appropriate answer?

Comment: i added to the code above :)

Comment: btw, instead of closing, one generally just marks something that helped as an answer so the question/answer could help other people as well. I flagged it for undeletion because it was a good question

Answer (score 0):

In a simplified version, I would just suggest to split building up the tabs and the content in 2 different variables, and fill them up according to the data that is coming back

After the loop went through, you could then concatenate both the headers and the content

I've build a small sample based on the original code, that should just do what you wanted it to do. Note that my [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) knowledge is very rusty

```
$rowContent = @(
    ("title1", "content"),
    ("title2", "content 2"),
    ("title3", "content 3")
);
$tabheader = "<ul>";
$tabcontent = "";
$idx = 0;

for ($idx = 0; $idx -lt $rowContent.length; $idx++) {
    $item = $rowContent[$idx];
    $tabheader += "<li><a href='#tabs-$($idx)'>$($item[0])</a></li>";
    $tabcontent += "<div id='tabs-$($idx)'>$($item[1])</div>";
}
$tabheader += "</ul>";
$rows = "<div id='tabs'>$($tabheader)$($tabcontent)</div>";
Write-Host $rows;
```

if you want to keep your multiline strings, you could also use the -f tag to do insert the values, like in the following example

```
$rowContent = @(
    ("title1", "content"),
    ("title2", "content 2"),
    ("title3", "content 3")
);
$tabheader = "";
$tabcontent = "";
$idx = 0;

for ($idx = 0; $idx -lt $rowContent.length; $idx++) {
    $item = $rowContent[$idx];
    $tabheader += @"
        <li>
            <a href='#tabs-{0}'>{1}</a>
        </li>

"@ -f $idx, $item[0];
    $tabcontent += @"
    <div id='tabs-{0}'>
        {1}
    </div>

"@ -f $idx, $item[1];
}
$rows = @"
<div id='tabs'>
    <ul>
{0}
    </ul>
{1}
</div>
"@ -f $tabheader, $tabcontent;
Write-Host $rows;
```

which would output

```
<div id='tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href='#tabs-0'>title1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#tabs-1'>title2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#tabs-2'>title3</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <div id='tabs-0'>
        content
    </div>
    <div id='tabs-1'>
        content 2
    </div>
    <div id='tabs-2'>
        content 3
    </div>

</div>
```